# Accounting for empty values using fscanf in tab delimited text file

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, csv

So I'm trying to use `fscanf` to copy certain data from a tab delimited text file into variables but I'm having issues with empty/null values.

[image: Example text file, tab-delimited]

For example, I am trying to save the name, student number and test 2 as well as the average grade in their own variables in the program.

After checking for valid file opening, I've tried running a while loop similar to this

```
int main() {
    char name[10];
    char studentNumber[255];
    char test2[3];
    char average[3];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    while ((fscanf(file, " %*[^\t] %[^\t] %*[^\t] %[^\t] %*[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\t] %*[^\n]",
                   name, studentNumber, test2, average)) == 4) {
        (fscanf(file, " %*[^\t] %[^\t] %*[^\t] %[^\t] %*[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\t] %*[^\n]",
                name, studentNumber, test2, average);
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", name, studentNumber, test2, average);
    }
}
```

Output expected is zero or null values where there are no values found in the text file

```
Sarah "475-476-001" "100" "70"
Jordan "47273483" 0 0
Tim "432763-342" "70" "70"
```

But the actual output is

```
Jordan "78" "90" 
Tim "432763-342" "70"
```

It seems like `fscanf` isn't accounting for the empty values and is throwing off the 'indexing' for each columns values. It's also skipping some rows (which I assume is due to the `%*[^\n]` somehow).

Any ideas as to how I could account for the empty/null values in the text file?

Comment: You should probably just copy-paste an actual piece of code, as this is obviously not the code you're using. The format strings aren't surrounded in double quotes.

Comment: What happens if a value is NULL? 2 tabulations in a row?

Comment: When there's a null value it seems to disregard that null value as a value and assumes the next available value as the one stored to the variable. EG. Test 2 for Jordan is empty, so it assumes test 3 value for test 2.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` is probably not the best tool for this task, because of the limitations of scanf formats.

To start with, scanf never returns a zero-length string. That's considered a data error, and it results in format processing to stop. So while you can put `[^\t]` into a format, you need to be prepared for failure.

Second, scanf does not normally distinguish between different whitespace characters. If you put a space, tab or newline into a format (other than inside a character class), it will match any whitespace character, not just the matching one. Moreover, it will match a sequence of whitespace characters, thereby eliminating the evidence of an empty field.

So your best solution is to read the input a line at a time and then split it into fields.

But the usual C library function for splitting a line into fields, `strtok`, has a similar problem to scanf with empty fields. `strtok` considers any sequence of delimiter characters to be a single delimiter, which again makes empty fields vanish. Many C libraries include `strsep`, a non-standard extension which has the same awkward interface as `strtok` but treats each delimiter separately. So if you have that function and you don't mind the awkward interface, it's a reasonable solution. But it's not much more difficult to just search for tab delimiters yourself, using `strchr`.

Answer (score 0):

As *rici* explained, neither `fscanf()` nor `strtok()` are fit for this type of parsing exercise because they cannot handle empty fields. You should read one line at a time and use `strchr()` or `strcspn()` to analyse the contents and possibly `strdup()` or `strndup()` to extract string fields or `strtol()` for numeric fields.

There seems to be more problems in your code: `fscanf()` takes a `FILE*` as its first argument, not a filename, and you should not reparse with a second call inside the loop body.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char line[1024];
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open data.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        char *fields[8];
        char *p = line;

        for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
            // save the pointer to the start of the field
            fields[n] = p;
            // skip to the end of the field
            p += strcspn(p, "\t\n");
            if (*p != '\0') {
                // set a null terminator for the field and skip to the next one
                *p++ = '\0';
            }
        }
        char *name = fields[1];
        char *studentNumber = fields[3];
        char *test2 = fields[5];
        char *average = fields[6];
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", name, studentNumber, test2, average);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```